# How to properly pass a jquery value to php using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass a value from my jquery code to a php variable after a user inputs through a textbox, but I don't receive any value at all in the PHP side through POST.I'm using .change and .post, does anyone here knows how to do it properly?
here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#packagename").change(function(){
    var packagename = $('#packagename').val();
    var url = '{{url}}'; //localhost/test/test.php
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: url,
    dataType:html,
    data:{'val':packagename},   
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: You can't alter PHP variables with JavaScript, since PHP is a server-side language and thereby totally unaware of anything happening in the browser. POST requests is handled on the page you are posting to, and does not affect the page you are at.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#packagename").change(function(){
    var packagename = $('#packagename').val();
    var url = '{{url}}'; //localhost/test/test.php
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: url,
    dataType:text,
    data:{'val':packagename},  
    success:function(result){
alert(result);
} 
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: @NeilAntonio If it has a alert display, it mean your JS working, then what are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem that I can see offhand is that the `html` in `dataType:html,` needs to have quotes around it like this: `dataType: 'html',`. Otherwise your code will look for the variable `html`, not find it, and throw an error.

Comment: I already did, but still I don't receive any value in my php code:
echo $_POST['val']

Comment: Does your javascript console show any errors? Do you get any response from the server?

Comment: What output do you see when you do a `var_dump($_POST)` instead of `echo $_POST['val']`?

Comment: That probably means that the script isn't outputting *anything*, so the script might not being called at all. Are you calling `//localhost/test/test.php` using that exact syntax? If so, that will look for a file on your local drive. Try changing to `/localhost/test/test.php` and check the output.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
dataType
Type: String
The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).
```

change `dataType: html,` to `dataType: 'html',`

Comment: I already did, but still I don't receive any value in my php code:
echo $_POST['val']

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just putting the url into the url field instead of whatever that object is you are trying to use?

I will assume you are not trying to ajax to the page you are currently on and expecting the php variable to display on the current page.

Comment: Im trying to ajax it to the current page...do you have any ideas on how I could properly handle it?

Comment: For updating the current page, you would just do that with javascript. For storing the value in a database for example, you would ajax it to another php page that is used to write to the database. You could do both to simulate updating the current page.